# How to get the index of the highest value in a list per row in a Spark DataFrame? [PySpark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have done LDA topic modelling and have it stored in `lda_model`.

After transforming my original input dataset I retrieve a DataFrame. One of the columns is the topicDistribution where the probability of this row belonging to each topic from the LDA model. I therefore want to get the index of the maximul value in the list per row.

```
df -- | 'list_of_words' | 'index ' | 'topicDistribution' | 
       ['product','...']     0       [0.08,0.2,0.4,0.0001]
          .....             ...         ........
```

I want to transform df such that an additional column is added which is the argmax of the topicDistribution list per row.

```
df_transformed --  | 'list_of_words' | 'index' | 'topicDistribution' | 'topicID' |
                    ['product','...']     0     [0.08,0.2,0.4,0.0001]      2
                       ......            ....         .....              ....
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a user defined function to get the index of the maximum

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

max_index = f.udf(lambda x: x.index(max(x)), IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn("topicID", max_index("topicDistribution"))
```

---

Example

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as f
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([{"topicDistribution": [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]}])
>>> df.show()
+-----------------+
|topicDistribution|
+-----------------+
|  [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]|
+-----------------+

>>> max_index = f.udf(lambda x: x.index(max(x)), IntegerType())
>>> df.withColumn("topicID", max_index("topicDistribution")).show()
+-----------------+-------+
|topicDistribution|topicID|
+-----------------+-------+
|  [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]|      2|
+-----------------+-------+
```

---

Edit:

Since you mentioned that the lists in `topicDistribution` are numpy arrays, you can update the `max_index` `udf` as follows:

```
max_index = f.udf(lambda x: x.tolist().index(max(x)), IntegerType())
```

Comment: I get the following error

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @kspr You didn't mentioned that your data inside topicDistribution is a numpy array. Check my edit